# How can I round a float such that there are only two trailing digits after the decimal point?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding, significant-digits

I have a float number like 137.57667565656 but I would like to round it such that there are only two trailing digits after the decimal point like the new float number will be 137.58.

I tried this so far:

```
(Math.round((value*100)/100)).toFixed(2).toString();
```

But unfortunately, it rounds my value to 137.00. It adds the decimals places as zeroes, why?

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: Isn't 137.57667565656 reduced to 4 signifiant figures 137.6?

Comment: @RobG, sorry, I want it like 137.58 where the last digit is rounded and it's to two trailing digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What did you expect?

```
(value*100)/100
```

simply returns the original value of *value*, so

```
Math.round((value*100)/100))
```

is identical to:

```
Math.round(value)
```

you then have:

```
Math.round(value).toFixed(2).toString();
```

so *value* is rounded to an integer, *toFixed* will add two decimal places and return a string so the *toString* part is redundant. If you wish to round *value* to four decimal places, then:

```
value.toFixed(4)
```

will do the job:

```
var x = 137.57667565656;

console.log(x.toFixed(4)); // 137.5767
```

If you want to round it to 2 places but present it as 4, then:

```
Number(x.toFixed(2)).toFixed(4)  // 137.5800
```

Comment: Four fixed fractional figures is not the same as four significant figures.

Comment: @Merchako—yes, hence my comment on the OP. It wasn't clear to me what the OP wanted. ;-)

Comment: I just proposed an edit so we can actually get a useful question out of this instead of waiting for the OPer to never respond.

Comment: @Merchako, I apologize haha. It was a while back but what I wanted was something like I mentioned in the post 137.57 with two trailing digits after the decimal point, so your edit isn't correct Merchako. RobG was right.... I think I just used the Math.Round and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler answer that works for all significant figures, not just four.
JavaScript provides a [built-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) `Number.toPrecision()` function that returns a string representing a number in significant digits.

```
var value = 137.57667565656;
var strVal = value.toPrecision(4);
>> 137.6
```

There have been a lot of misconceptions about significant figures on this post. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) to refresh your memory. See @RobG's answer for why your original method was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Two zeroes are added because prior to all you do `Math.round`:

> If the fractional portion of number is .5 or greater, the argument is
>   rounded to the next higher integer. If the fractional portion of
>   number is less than .5, the argument is rounded to the next lower
>   integer.

[(taken from here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

What you need is to drop `Math.round`:

```
(value*100)/100).toFixed(4).toString();
```

See it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0fe5mm95/

Comment: And the point of `((value*100)/100)` is (assuming the syntax error is fixed)? ;-)

Comment: @RobG it was in the question. I assume Kala J uses other values. The problem is not in the division, but in using `Math.round`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Apparently i misunderstood the question. When I tried to answer it was (at least in the title) about significant digits.

This answer lines up with [Wikipedia's definition of significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). It solves the general problem, for any number of significant digits, in three steps:

1. figure out number of digits with log10 (negative if `-1<x<1`, e.g 5 for 12345, or -2 for 0.01)
2. round the number at the correct position (e.g. if x=12345 with three significant digits, then round the 45 to 00)
3. append the required number of zeros on the right

And that's all. Except the zero, which has no significant digits. (I went for "0.00" when asking for three significant digits, but 0 or 0.0 would be fine also)

```
function toStringWithSignificantDigits( x, len ){
    if(x==0) return x.toFixed(len-1); // makes little sense for 0
    var numDigits = Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.abs(x)));
    var rounded = Math.round(x*Math.pow(10,len-numDigits))*Math.pow(10,numDigits-len); 
    return rounded.toFixed(Math.max(len-numDigits,0));  
}


function testIt(x,len){
    console.log( "format " + x + " to " + len + " significant digits: " + toStringWithSignificantDigits(x,len)); 
}

testIt(12.345,6);  // 12.3450
testIt(12.345,5);  // 12.345
testIt(12.345,4);  // 12.35
testIt(12.345,3);  // 12.3
testIt(12.345,2);  // 12
testIt(12.345,1);  // 10

testIt(0.012345,7);  // 0.01234500
testIt(0.012345,6);  // 0.0123450
testIt(0.012345,5);  // 0.012345
testIt(0.012345,4);  // 0.01235
testIt(0.012345,3);  // 0.0123
testIt(0.012345,2);  // 0.012
testIt(0.012345,1);  // 0.01

testIt(0,3); // 0.00, zero is a special case, as it has no significant digit
```