# Format a number to three sig figs with SI units

Tags: javascript

I would like to format an integer to 3 significant figures using SI units. For example:

```
1     => '1'
999   => '999'
1234  => '1.23k'
1235  => '1.24k'
```

The gross hack of a function I have is below, and still does not satisfy all my tests. The problems I run into involve detecting when `9…` will round up to `10…` and thus require one fewer decimal at the end.

```js
tests = [[9,'9'],[1,'1'],[10,'10'],[99,'99'],[100,'100'],[999,'999'],
        [1000,'1.00k'],[1004,'1.00k'],[1009,'1.01k'],[1472,'1.47k'],
        [1926,'1.93k'],[1999,'2.00k'],[2000,'2.00k'],[9813,'9.81k'],
        [9990,'9.99k'],[9999,'10.0k'],[10000,'10.0k'],[10010,'10.0k'],
        [60712,'60.7k'],[98712,'98.7k'],[99949,'99.9k'],[99950,'100k'],
        [99999,'100k'],[100000,'100k'],[400499,'400k'],[999499,'999k'],
        [999500,'1.00M'],[999999,'1.00M'],[1000000,'1.00M'],
        [1234567,'1.23M'],[12345678,'12.3M'],[123456789,'123M']]

tests.forEach( ([n,expected]) => {
    const actual = siRound(n)
    console.log(n, actual, actual==expected ? '=' : '≠', expected)
})

function siRound(x) {
    if (x<1e3) return x+'';
    const digits = Math.log10(x) | 0
    const tier = digits/3 | 0
    let str = (x / 10**(tier*3)).toFixed(2-(digits%3))
    // Turn "10.00" into "10.0" and "100.0" into "100"
    str = str.replace(/^(.{3})\..+|^(.{4}).+/, '$1$2')
    return str + (['','k','M','G','T'])[tier]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `Number.prototype.toFixed(3)`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl `(1234).toFixed(3) => '1234.000'`, not `1.23k`. As you can see, my code does already use `toFixed()` in some part.

Comment: Sounds like you want `toPrecision` a la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37397415/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey That is definitely a useful part in fixing this, thanks! Not quite an answer on its own, but almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @HereticMonkey pointing out the presence of [`toPrecision()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision), here's an answer that works, though it feels a little bit gross to me. I'll switch acceptance to a cleaner, fully-working answer if someone posts one.

```js
// Note: intentionally returns integers below 1,000 unchanged.
// For true precision across all numbers, remove the first line.
function siRound(n, precision=3) {
    if (x<1e3) return x+''
    let tier = Math.log10(x)/3 | 0
    let str = (x / 10**(tier*3)).toPrecision(precision)
    if (str>=1e3) str = (x / 10**(++tier*3)).toPrecision(precision)
    return str + (['','k','M','G','T','P','E','Z','Y'])[tier]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your method recursive like. Add this, check before you return:

```
if (str.length>4) { 
      siRound(str)
}
```

```js
tests = [[9,'9'],[1,'1'],[10,'10'],[99,'99'],[100,'100'],[999,'999'],
        [1000,'1.00k'],[1004,'1.00k'],[1009,'1.01k'],[1472,'1.47k'],
        [1926,'1.93k'],[1999,'2.00k'],[2000,'2.00k'],[9813,'9.81k'],
        [9990,'9.99k'],[9999,'10.0k'],[10000,'10.0k'],[10010,'10.0k'],
        [60712,'60.7k'],[98712,'98.7k'],[99949,'99.9k'],[99950,'100k'],
        [99999,'100k'],[100000,'100k'],[400499,'400k'],[999499,'999k'],
        [999500,'1.00M'],[999999,'1.00M'],[1000000,'1.00M'],
        [1234567,'1.23M'],[12345678,'12.3M'],[123456789,'123M']]

tests.forEach( ([n,expected]) => {
    const actual = siRound(n)
    console.log(n, actual, actual==expected ? '=' : '≠', expected)
})

function siRound(x) {
    if (x<1e3) return x+'';
    const digits = Math.log10(x) | 0
    const tier = digits/3 | 0
    let str = (x / 10**(tier*3)).toFixed(2-(digits%3))
    // Turn "10.00" into "10.0" and "100.0" into "100"
    str = str.replace(/^(.{3})\..+|^(.{4}).+/, '$1$2')
    if (str.length>4) { ///Add this check
      siRound(str)
    }
    return str + (['','k','M','G','T'])[tier]
}
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting hack, but -1 because it doesn't work. Still has `999500` => `1000k` instead of `1.00M`. You don't change anything by calling `siRound()` recursively, as you do not do anything with the result of calling it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
tests = [[9,'9'],[1,'1'],[10,'10'],[99,'99'],[100,'100'],[999,'999'],
        [1000,'1.00k'],[1004,'1.00k'],[1009,'1.01k'],[1472,'1.47k'],
        [1926,'1.93k'],[1999,'2.00k'],[2000,'2.00k'],[9813,'9.81k'],
        [9990,'9.99k'],[9999,'10.0k'],[10000,'10.0k'],[10010,'10.0k'],
        [60712,'60.7k'],[98712,'98.7k'],[99949,'99.9k'],[99950,'100k'],
        [99999,'100k'],[100000,'100k'],[400499,'400k'],[999499,'999k'],
        [999500,'1.00M'],[999999,'1.00M'],[1000000,'1.00M'],
        [1234567,'1.23M'],[12345678,'12.3M'],[123456789,'123M']]

const siRound = x => {
  if (x < 1e3) {
    return x;
  }
  let roudedX = x;
  let tier = 0;
  while (roudedX >= 1000) {
    roudedX /= 1000;
    tier += 1;
  }
  roudedX = Number.parseFloat(roudedX.toPrecision(3));
  if (Math.abs(roudedX - 1e3) < Number.EPSILON) {
    roudedX = 1;
    tier += 1;
  }
  return roudedX.toPrecision(3) + ['', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T'][tier];
}

tests.forEach(([n,expected]) => {
  const actual = siRound(n)
  console.log(n, actual, actual==expected ? '=' : '≠', expected)
})
```